# $.fn.jquery showing older version when updated jquery to newer

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have an issue with jQuery version. In my angular1 application am used jQuery 1.11.0.

Recently I updated it to 3.3.1 and included the reference into index.html.
But unfortunately it didnt work, i donno the reason but i couldn't find any error in console.

So I decided to use 2.2.4 and downloaded the script and copied to my application and it works for me.

But my problem is when I execute $.fn.jquery in chrome console it results version "1.11.0".

I used `

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But still it showing 1.11.0

Can anyone tell me why $.fn.jquery is showing version 1.11.0 still?

Comment: I tried and It show 3.3.1 for me.

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console. How many requests are there for a jQuery `.js` file? What are the URLs requested?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite

Comment: How $.fn.jquery find version of jQuery in application? Only from index.html or from any other?